# Javascript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Can anyone figure out why this is throwing a syntax error?  All of the code looks correct to me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname;

function ajaxinclude(url) 
{
    var pagerequest = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        pagerequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try {
            pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e){
            try{
                pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
        catch (e){}
        }
    }
    else
        return false

    pagerequest.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously 
    pagerequest.send(null)
    writecontent(pagerequest)
}

function writecontent(page_request){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || pagerequest.status==200)
    document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML = pagerequest.responseText;
}
```

It's throwing an error on line 7 -- var pagerequest = false;

If you comment it out, it just throws an error on the next line.  Any ideas?

**Thanks in advance for your help!!**

Comment: the error is just a simple "syntax error."  I have taken into account what the folks below have said and I am still getting errors.  The problem wasn't with the writecontent() function, it is with the ajaxinclude() function.  I also would like to mention that you do NOT need semicolons in JavaScript.

Comment: Usually these things happen when you copy&paste code from a website or a pdf document that uses fancy unicode characters to make the code look better. But I suppose the error message is wrong and the real problem is somewhere else. To check if it's a real syntax error, try putting some code outside of the function and see if it runs. If it runs then it's impossible for the function to contain a syntax error. In this case maybe there is a bug in the XMLHttpRequest implementation or a syntax error in the response body.

Answer (score 2):

Yopur writecontent is wronge (argument naming) try:

```
function writecontent(page_request){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || page_request.status==200)
    document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML = page_request.responseText;
}
```

Also, there's no real value to this:

```
var pagerequest = false;
```

Since you never return it without setting it somewhere else in your code might as well just be:

```
var pagerequest;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `writecontent` function, you call the argument `page_request`, but then refer to it in the function body as `pagerequest` (without the underscore).

Otherwise, your code should be working -- see http://jsfiddle.net/2eynH/ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - utilize http://jslint.com/

It does not like your `writecontent` function.

And `pagerequest = new XMLHttpRequest()` is missing a semicolon.

Also, I also like to "rip" my javascript through YUI Compressor to help reveal syntax errors.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Some more missing semicolons:

```
pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

One more thing.  Even though javascript allows you to do something, does not mean that you should.  Declaring pagerequest as a boolean, then setting it to an ActiveXObject is a little confusing.  I would probably initialize it to null.  Then "test" for null later on down in the code.

Comment: Semicolons are (generally) optional in Javascript, which does [semicolon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons on almost all lines.

Cleaned up code:

```
function ajaxinclude(url) {
    var pagerequest;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        pagerequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try {
            pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                pagerequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (ec) {}
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    pagerequest.open('GET', url, false); // get page synchronously 
    pagerequest.send();
    writecontent(pagerequest);
}

function writecontent (page_request) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1 || page_request.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML = page_request.responseText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not valid. Semi-colons are added to your code when doesnt have it or it thinks it should have it.

So in

```
function ajaxinclude(url) 
{
    var pagerequest = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        pagerequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try {
```

the javascript compiler will do the following

```
function ajaxinclude(url); // note the semi-color meaning the { starts floating in the middle of nowhere
{
    var pagerequest = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        pagerequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try { //and so on
```

As most people have suggested run JSLint over it to see the mistakes.

**Edit from comment**

You can see the Semi-colon insertion details in the [blog](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/)

Comment: Does it really do this?  Are you saying that the opening brace *must* be on the same line as the `function` keyword?  If so I've been doing it wrong forever.

Comment: @segfault Yea it does do that but if you minify your code normally you can get away with it. I have added a link to my answer showing it

Comment: No! A function statement always has a body. Inserting a semicolon before the body *creates* a syntax error. This is different to a return statement. The language dictates that you cannot put a line break between the `return` keyword and the return value expression. So inserting a semicolon before the line break *eliminates* a syntax error.